# Getting data from mssql table based on startdate and enddate

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am writing a query to select data from a table called contest.
each contest has start date and enddate. I want to select all the contest details from the contest table if the current date is between start date and end date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from contest
where dtBegin <= getDate() and getDate() <= dtEnd
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from contest 
where getDate() between startdate and enddate
```

`getDate()` returns you the current date and time.

Answer (score 0):

out of interest why is this tagged c# what are you trying to achieve with this?

if your trying to get this into an app some how you could use either a SqlDataReader or LinqtoSQL (plus others)

Comment: Consider making this a comment? I see part of an answer here, but mostly just a comment.